# View cart button text color change Wordpress Storefront

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I am using storefront theme and I am struggling with changing the color of the text of the "view to cart" button. When you click on "add to cart", it shows the button but the text is the same color as the background of the button, so you can`t see what is written there. I have tried everything that I found on the internet, but none of it works.. I also tried to change every color on each that I found when clicking on "Inspect element"..adding the !important everytime..

You can try to click on the "Přidat do košíku" here and inspect it on your own - https://www.alloyware.cz/produkty/ .[image]

Comment: Since you are using Elementor you may have the same problem with other links on other pages. You should optimize the `.elementor-kit-81 a` rule. Since the `elementor-kit-81` class is applied to the `<body>`, it will override all CSS rules with non-specific selectors. I recommend that you check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS

```
a.added_to_cart.wc-forward {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```